# Is it a good idea to store in my email confirmation emails for internet accounts?

Tags: email, security

Currently all the emails I get when signing up for internet accounts I keep in a folder called "Accounts". Anytime I forget a username, or whether or not I have an account, I just search my emails.

I'm starting to move my data to a password protected password manager but was also wondering if it was a smart idea from a security standpoint to keep these emails in my account as it would be a treasure chest if someone gained access to my account.

edit: they're mostly the "welcome to X" type emails, not the "click here to activate ones". Most of them have a username or the name used during the signup process.

Comment: no definitive answer here....all you'll get is opinions

Comment: However, if someone did gain unchecked access to your e-mail account, any service that you may run that's dependent on it (Facebook, forum logins, banking sites, etc) would be compromised as well, regardless of whether you still keep those registration mails, because if you actively use such services, they quickly flood your account with mail, which can be quickly tracked back.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the 'click here to confirm' type emails ? Those links are (should) be a one-time use link which is of no use once you've used it the first time so you may as well remove them.

If you mean emails of the type 'your password is X' then a) stop using that company, their security sucks as they have just sent your password in plain text (and have likely stored it in a reversable encryption type for the forgotten password emails too), or b) set your password to something very long, not used anywhere else and begin planning how to achieve (a).

Comment: They're the post-completion emails, and their contents vary, usually with a username, name I used, and further instructions.